# How to use DBPointer bson type in MongoDB 3.2

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

According to mongoDB [docs](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/bson-types/), DBPointer is introduced in MongoDB 3.2 as data type. But they haven't given any example. I was trying to insert the value for this in one collection. But I'm not getting that how to insert document with a DBPoitner in the Collection.

Can anyone show me an example?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per this [doc](http://srcrr.com/java/mongo/2.7.3/reference/com/mongodb/DBPointer.html),

```
DBPointer (String ns, ObjectId id)
```

> There are two Parameters:
>
> `ns`  namespace to point to
>
> `id`  value of `_id` (ObjectId)

To insert it into document,

```
> db.dbpointers.insert({p: new DBPointer('tt', new ObjectId("56c070fe43fec980d26669d5"))});
> db.dbpointers.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56d6dfbde1c528593e02435c"), "p" : DBPointer("tt", ObjectId("56c070fe43fec980d26669d5")) }
```

However, per the [BSON spec](http://bsonspec.org/spec.html),

> "\x0C" e_name string (byte*12)  DBPointer — Deprecated